# Dynamically create regex pattern for match

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

```
using Visual.Web.Developer.2010.Express;
```

N00b here,
I'm in a pickle.. I'm trying to create a web application that has 2 text areas where the user can input 2 lists of names (for identifications sake, these text areas are `aT2` and  `aT1`).. `aT2` contains names, and `aT1` contains those same names, but I've altered them slightly to my preference. The thing is that `aT2` contains names that `aT1` doesn't have (which means I want to exclude the ones that aren't there after I filter through `aT2`) Basically searching through `aT2` to see which ones match.

Here's a few in `aT1`:

```
ABC9910A
ABC42554
LOW3381
BD6210HFP
NWP448A1S
OTT123A04NS
```

Here's a few in `aT2`:

```
APPLEMACHINE    Y   ABC9910AIMAP
APPLEMACHINE    Y   ABC42554AIRAJZ
BANANABOI   Y   LOW33811CBZ
LLBLEAD TECHN   Y   NWP448A1S3LWXFTMA1
LLBLEAD TECHN   Y   OTT123A04NS4NSGATMA1
```

What i'm asking about is how would I dynamically create a new regex pattern for each item in `aT1`? You see how the first item in `aT1` would match the first item in `aT2`? They almost always will not be in order like that... But dynamically create a search pattern for regex to search through `aT2` for each item in 'aT1'.. If there is a match, it would print out that whole line of text before the linefeed in the text area.. Was I specific enough?? Is this even possible??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Would [**`string.Contains`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) suffice, or is a regular expression necessary?

Comment: @mellamokb I didn't know that existed.. I think it would. No it's not necessary

Comment: Do you have LINQ available to use?

Comment: @mellamokb I can, but I think `string.contains` will do.. Would you recommend LINQ over `string.contains`?

Comment: No, LINQ would be a simple way to compare all the entries in aT1 with all the entries in aT2, using a `.Join` or something like that.  More for the higher-level data processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a RegEx pattern might be a bit of overkill for what you're asking. You might want to look at simply using [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx).